# ¿Porque recibo este error en my app de Android?

Tags: php, java, api

Estoy intentando conectar mí código de java con una API en PHP.
Este es mí el código Java que se ejecuta al hacr click en el botón:

```
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://mikelmoli.000webhostapp.com/PHP/add.php");
                Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                params.put("name", n);

                StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
                for(Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()){
                    if(postData.length()!=0) postData.append('&');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    postData.append('=');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                }
                byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
               os.write(postDataBytes);

                Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

                for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
                    System.out.print((char)c);


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("TAG",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Cuando runeo la app y hago click en el botón me salta el siguiente error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                  Process: farmacia.fuck, PID: 14668
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{farmacia.fuck/farmacia.fuck.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:245)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:128)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:370)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:298)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:399)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:349)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:203)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>                                                                      at farmacia.fuck.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
>                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
>                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>   02-16 10:22:14.518 14668-14668/farmacia.fuck I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14668 SIG: 9

Se supone que el error lo da en esta línea pero no sé por qué lo hace:

```
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

El código PHP es el siguiente, aunque dudo que el error tenga que ver con este:

```html
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO txumino(Laputxa) VALUES('$name')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Si quieres hacer una llamada de ese tipo la tienes que hacer por medio de un asynktask. Con eso creo que solucionarás tu problema. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Gracias, no sabía que era necesario

Comment: Aquí hay otra persona que explica bastante bien su uso: http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/tareas-en-segundo-plano-en-android-i-thread-y-asynctask/

Answer (score -1):

En el sitio puedes encontrar información acerca del error [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

[Preguntas acerca de **NetworkOnMainThreadException**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20NetworkOnMainThreadException%20)

> [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) : error el cual se provoca cuando
>   tratas de realizar operaciones en el hilo principal (Main thread), lo
>   cual es incorrecto.

Para solucionar esto puedes usar un `AsyncTask`, agrega en `doInBackground()` la tarea que deseas realizar:

```
public class ConexionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {

          /***************************************/
 try {

                URL url = new URL("https://mikelmoli.000webhostapp.com/PHP/add.php");
                Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                params.put("name", n);

                StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
                for(Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()){
                    if(postData.length()!=0) postData.append('&');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    postData.append('=');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                }
                byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
               os.write(postDataBytes);

                Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));

                for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
                    System.out.print((char)c);


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("TAG",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
          /***************************************/
            return true;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isAvalable) {

        }


         @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

    }
```

Al dar click en el botón simplemente llama la ejecución del `AsyncTask`:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

     new ConexionTask().execute();    

}
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -negativo, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el